# bootstrap input group add on google chrome

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I want to ask , 
why on chrome my input-group-addon seems bad style?
but on mozilla everything is ok.

here is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9JJ5.jpg

There's some style i must edit or add to my bootstrap css ?

my code :

```
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width: 75px;">NIK</span>
  <input class="form-control" style="max-width: 373px;" type="text" id="niks" name="niks" placeholder="NIK" value="<?php echo $row_edit['nik']; ?>" disabled="disabled"/><br/>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a css reset to remove browser customizations.

One of them: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Maybe it doesn't solve your specific problem, I didn't try it. Anyway, sure it will help ypu to avoid future problems like this.

Also I recommend you to avoid inline styling.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback , but that not help to solve my problem , but just broke my main css style :(

Comment: Do you included the reset file **before** your main css file?

Comment: yes of course , i included it before and try add after , the result seems same